# Как получить ID сессии?

Tags: php

С сайта TestDomen1.com, который я обслуживаю
нужно выполнить скрипт (TestDomen1.comp/Site.php), который обращается к стороннему ресурсу
TestDomen2.com для передачи данных с TestDomen1.com

Ресурсы TestDomen2.com и TestDomen2.com расположены на разных доменах и на разных серверах.

скрипт TestDomen1.comp/Site.php (пример)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
$_SESSION['a']=10;
var_dump($_SESSION['a']);
echo '<br>';
exit(
'<a href="http://TestDomen2.com/GetData.php">вернуть контент с помощью Curl</a>'.
'<br>'.
'<a href="http://TestDomen1.com/pContent.php">вернуть контент</a>'
);
?>
```

Известно, что скрипт TestDomen2.com/GetData.php выполняет загрузку
контента, с помощью библиотеки Curl, подготовка которого, выполняется скриптом 
TestDomen1.com/pContent.php например так:

скрипт TestDomen2.com/GetData.php (пример)

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
  $curlh = curl_init();
  $url = 'http://TestDomen1.com/pContent.php';
  $postdata = array('123');
  curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata));
  $out = curl_exec($curlh);
  curl_close($curlh);
  echo $out;  
?>
```

скрипт TestDomen1.com/pContent.php (пример)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION)) { 
  var_dump($_SESSION);
}   
else {
  echo 'session empty';  
}
```

При загрузке контента посредством скрипта TestDomen2.com/GetData.php
теряется содержимое сессии определенное в TestDomen1.comp/Site.php

скрипт TestDomen2.com/GetData.php не доступен для редактирования (создал грубый пример)
т. е. передать SID в этот скрипт 
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID='.session_id()); не возможно.

Использование глобальной сессии также нежелательно т.к. текущие данные сессии могут быть переписаны.

Данные из сессии, которая стартует в TestDomen1.comp/Site.php нужны для
организации аудита операций, выполняемых при обработке данных контента, скриптом TestDomen1.com/pContent.php

Как в данном случае получить в TestDomen1.com/pContent.php
SID сессии открытой в TestDomen1.comp/Site.php ?

Comment: http://www.php.su/session_id

Comment: в функции session_id() нужно указать в параметре ID сессии. Но сначала его нужно получить, как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();


$name=session_id();
print_r($name);

?>
```

Comment: вызов $name=session_id() в TestDomen1.com/pContent.php, который запускается из  TestDomen2.com/GetData.php с помощью curl возвращает id новой сессии, а мне нужно получить id сессии, которая была запущена в скрипте TestDomen1.comp/Site.php.

Comment: как вариант запиши в файл  file_put_contents() а потом от туда возьми

Comment: В этом случае id сессии может быть перезаписан в этом файле другими пользователями  и будут прочитаны  чужие данные.

Comment: Пиши столбиком я вообще не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: переход на TestDomen1.com/pContent.php выполняется с помощью curl со страницы другого сайта TestDomen2.com/GetData
Если прочитать содержимое файла
file_get_contents(sids.txt)

[1 сессия пользователя a; 2 сессия пользователя b; 3 сессия пользователя a (c другого хоста); 4 сессия пользователя m;
.... сессия пользователя n]

со страницы моего сайта TestDomen1.com/pContent.php 

Как определить в этом списке, что мне нужен session id = 3, а не другой. С чем его сравнивать при 
отсутствии соответствующего идентификатора в TestDomen1.com/pContent.php.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: При переходе с TestDomen2.com/GetData на TestDomen1.com/pContent.php, браузер этот заголовок не устанавливает - переход выполняется с неотображаемой страницы